# How can I detect duplicated items in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to find duplicated objects and add hasDuplicate: true property, but not the first one. Methods should be run after one element.

The example array

```
 items: [
  {
    checked: false,
    desc: "",
    id: "396",
    value: "Lorem",
  },
  {
    checked: false,
    desc: "",
    id: "230",
    value: "Lorem"
  },
  {
    checked: false,
    desc: "",
    id: "396",
    value: "Lorem",
    hasDuplicate: true
  },
  {
    checked: false,
    desc: "",
    id: "396",
    value: "Lorem",
    hasDuplicate: true
  },
  {
    checked: false,
    desc: "",
    id: "230",
    value: "Lorem",
    hasDuplicate: true
  },
]
```

What is an efficient way to detect duplicate items in an array with ES6?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Give a [mre] **of code**, that generally doesn't need much translation.

Comment: do some research `Array.prototype.filter or reduce` or just use a `for` loop [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I think it's clear, as is seen in the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map()` to traverse your array and check whether the `hash` (`Object.entries()` concatenated) is already seen:

```js
const src = [{checked:false,desc:"",id:"396",value:"Lorem",},{checked:false,desc:"",id:"230",value:"Lorem"},{checked:false,desc:"",id:"396",value:"Lorem"},{checked:false,desc:"",id:"396",value:"Lorem"},{desc:"",id:"230",checked:false,value:"Lorem"}],
  
      dedupe = (a, hashMap=[]) => a.map(o => {
        const hash = Object
                      .entries(o)
                      .sort(([a],[b]) => 
                        a.localeCompare(b))
                      .flat()
                      .join('\ud8ff')
        return !hashMap.includes(hash) ? 
        (hashMap.push(hash), o) :
        {...o, hasDuplicate: true}
      })
    
console.log(dedupe(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Seems a nice solution and it's working but includes has poor support for browsers like ie11, maybe I can use indexOf right?

Comment: @ÖmerDoğan : just checked [the latest edit of that codepen](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/QWymQrX?editors=0012) in IE11 and it seems to return expected result properly

Comment: @Thomas : fair point, mate. Thanks. Got that fixed. You may safely delete your comment as it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

isIdentical() method will compare two objects and returns true if they are identical.

```
 const isIdentical = (obj1, obj2) => {
      let flag = true;
      Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
        if(obj1[key] !== obj2[key]){
          flag = false;
          return false;
        }
      });
      return flag;
    };
```

Now reduce method will help us loop through the array.

```
items.reduce((unique, item) => {
  const index = unique.findIndex( u => isIdentical(u, item));
  if(index < 0){
    return [...unique, item];
  } else {
    item.hasDuplicate = true;
    return unique;
  }
}, []);

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score -1):

This sets the hasDuplicate property of every duplicate item except the first one based on their id

```
items.forEach((d, i) => {
  if(i == items.map(d => d.id).indexOf(d.id)) {
    d.hasDuplicate = true;
  }
})
```